# Is resharper right about this code being unreachable?

Tags: c#, resharper, nullable

Reshaper said the left hand side of `??` was never null even though its type is `int?`

```
        _savedMediaFileId = mediaFile.MediaFileId ?? _savedMediaFileId;
```

The auto refactor "remove unreachable code" turned it into this:

```
        _savedMediaFileId = (int) mediaFile.MediaFileId;
```

Is that right or is Resharper making a mistake here?

My idea was that since int? is nullable, then then I could use ?? to keep the existing value in the case it is null.

Here's my unit test (in progress)

```
[TestClass]
public class MediaRepositoryTest
{
    private const string SiteId = "3";

    private const string ConnectionString =
        @"Data Source=dvmind\mssqlsites;Database=***********;User Name=sa;Password=**************";

    private string _mediaSourceName = "TestMediaSourceName";
    private string _mediaTypeName = "TestMediaTypeName";
    private string _mediaSourceAddress = "TestMediaSourceAddress";
    private string _mediaFileAddress = "TestMediaFileAddress";

    private int _savedMediaFileId = 0;

    private string GetGuidString()
    {
        return Convert.ToBase64String(Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray());
    }

    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestInitialize()
    {
        _mediaSourceName = _mediaSourceName + GetGuidString();
        _mediaTypeName = _mediaTypeName + GetGuidString();
        _mediaSourceAddress = _mediaSourceAddress + GetGuidString();
        _mediaFileAddress = _mediaFileAddress + GetGuidString();
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void TestCleanup()
    {
        using (var db = new SiteContext(ConnectionString))
        {
            if (_savedMediaFileId != 0)
            {
                (from c in db.MediaFiles where c.MediaFileId == _savedMediaFileId select c).ToList()
                    .ForEach(c => db.MediaFiles.Remove(c));
            }

            (from c in db.MediaSources where c.MediaSourceName == _mediaSourceName select c).ToList()
                .ForEach(c => db.MediaSources.Remove(c));

            (from c in db.MediaTypes where c.MediaTypeName == _mediaTypeName select c).ToList()
                .ForEach(c => db.MediaTypes.Remove(c));
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void SaveMediaTest()
    {
        var mediaSource = new MediaSource
        {
            MediaSourceName = _mediaSourceName,
            MediaSourceAddress = _mediaSourceAddress
        };

        var mediaType = new MediaType
        {
            MediaTypeName = _mediaTypeName
        };

        var mediaFile = new MediaFile
        {
            SiteId = SiteId,
            MediaFileAddress = _mediaFileAddress,
            MediaSource = mediaSource,
            MediaType = mediaType
        };

        var connectionStringProvider =
            Mock.Of<IConnectionStringProvider>(c => c.GetConnectionString() == ConnectionString);

        var repository = new MediaRepository(connectionStringProvider);

        Assert.IsTrue(mediaFile.MediaFileId == 0);

        repository.SaveMedia(mediaFile);

        Assert.IsTrue(mediaFile.MediaFileId != 0);

        _savedMediaFileId = mediaFile.MediaFileId ?? _savedMediaFileId;

        //using (var db = new SiteContext(ConnectionString))
        //{  
        //}
    }
```

Comment: Can you post a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem? Perhaps R# has inferred the non-nullity from a previous condition?

Comment: That's odd, Aaron. I use resharper and set up a similar scenario just to see what would happen and it doesn't give me that warning. What version of Resharper are you using? Maybe its outdated and they have fixed it already?

Comment: Is the `MediaFileId` property of the `MediaFile` type initialized on object creation somehow like in the constructor?

Comment: @itsme86, yeah it's called an object initializer

Comment: @AaronAnodide Well I don't see you initializing that property in the code you posted. Certainly not in the object initializer that you posted.

Comment: it because i'm using a live data context and that property is an auto incremented identity

Comment: @AaronAnodide Then it would never be null... I don't see the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

Now that you've posted a complete example, I think the reason you are getting unreachable code, is due to the Assert conditions that precede this line;

```
Assert.IsTrue(mediaFile.MediaFileId == 0);
```

If mediaFile.MediaFileId is null, the program exits on this line, if its not, then the warning is correct; mediaFile.MediaFileId cannot be null on the line you highlight;

```
_savedMediaFileId = mediaFile.MediaFileId ?? _savedMediaFileId;
```

Also, if the definition of `SaveMedia` took a `ref MediaFile` that would also impact the warning, because it is then possible (as far as ReSharper is concerned) that the value is changed again to Null by;

```
repository.SaveMedia(mediaFile);
```

Either of these changes will impact the presence of the warning.

Answer (score 2):

ReSharper is likely inferring here that `mediaFile.MediaFileId` can never have the value `null` even though the type is `int?`.  Hence it's suggesting that you skip the `null` check entirely and go straight for the value

A clearer example is the following

```
string s = "hello world";
if (s != null) { 
  ...
}
```

In this case `s` can be `null` practically because it is of type `string` and `null` is a valid value.  However in this specific context `s` can never be `null` hence ReSharper would flag this check as unnecessary

Comment: It's somewhat surprising (to me at least) that it then chooses to cast instead of `.Value`...

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a guess, but I think what's happening here (based on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

When you declare someting int?, it doesn't create a reference type that can be null.  Instead, it creates `Nullable<T>` which is a `struct` meaning it cannot be Null b/c it is a value type.  That struct besides the value contains a boolean flag that tells it if it is null of if value is valid.

Hence, doing `int? ??` is essentially testing a struct for null value which it can never be.  It does not test `Nullable<T>.HasValue` which is a way to test if is "null" or not.

Hence the ReSharper complaint.

Comment: Normally that would be so, but the compiler knows about `Nullable<T>` and treats it specially.

Comment: I wonder how ReSharper does its analysis. If it doesn't know about this compiler understanding, that it got a bug...

Comment: No, actually it's much smarter than that. The other answers explain.